# Как избежать необходимости повторной авторизации пользователей при очередном развертывании приложения

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat, spring-security

Делаю рефакторинг уже работающего java web-приложения со spring-security, запущенного на tomcat.

Пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль и авторизуется в нём. Но когда возникает необходимость что-то поменять в коде, сделать рефакторинг, то приходится удалять старый war-файл и папку, заливать новый war. Таким образом пользователю приходится авторизовываться снова, что для меня абсолютно неприемлемо.

Каким образом данную проблему можно разрешить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранять где то информацию о сессиях пользователей, чтобы после перезагрузки или обновления они никуда не пропадали.
Если вы используете spring security, то можно расмотреть механизм сохранения пользовательских сесий в базу данных. При этом необязательно иметь какую то реляционную бд, вроде mysql, postgresql и тд. Достаточно h2 с сохранением в файл. Разумеется такой вариант только для pet проектов. Подробный туториал можно почитать [здесь](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-jdbc-session)